# The real name of “square power” of the term of one multivariate polynomial？

Tags: polynomials

The real name of square power of the term of one multivariate polynomial？

In my text,

$x_1^2x_2x_3$ the square power is called (2,1,1)

How can I find some more things about this? Is it really called "squre power"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M. Artin (*Algebra*, 1991) calls it a "multi-index".

I don't see how calling it a "square power" would make sense. Where's the square?

Comment: ok, good to know that, I find one wiki page also.